# Teracopy: "File read" vs "OK" status

Tags: teracopy

When copying with Teracopy, the Status column sometimes reads "File read" and sometimes "OK", along with a green check mark.

The files marked "File read" seem to have been copied fine (I tested a random set of files; they work).

What is the difference? Should I worry when the status is not "OK"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering the same as I was having this issue as well. The technical support (techsupport@codesector.com) answered to me as follows:

> “File read” means that the file has been read into the memory, while “OK” means it has been written to the disk.

However, the files marked "File read" seem to have been copied fine on my computer as well, so I think it's a bug (it's probably worth comparing the size of the destination folder with the size of the source folder, or do some more advanced checks).

[image]

[image]